# Converting Encryption code from vb.NET to java

Tags: java, vb.net, encryption

I need help converting my vb.net code to java and produce the same encrypted string as in vb.net

```
Public Function AES_Encrypt(ByVal input As String) As String
    Dim AES As New System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged
    Dim Hash_AES As New System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
    Dim encrypted As String = ""
    Try
        Dim hash(31) As Byte
        Dim temp As Byte() = Hash_AES.ComputeHash(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("mykey1"))
        Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 0, 16)
        Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 15, 16)
        AES.Key = hash
        AES.Mode = Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.ECB
        Dim DESEncrypter As System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform = AES.CreateEncryptor
        Dim Buffer As Byte() = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input)
        encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(DESEncrypter.TransformFinalBlock(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length))
        Return encrypted
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Function
```

i have tried the following java code but im getting an exception

```
   import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
public class SimpleCrypto {
     public static String encrypt(String seed, String cleartext) throws Exception {
         byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes("US-ASCII"));
         byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes());
         return toHex(result);
 }



 private static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {

        MessageDigest md;
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

        // md.update(seed);

         byte[] temp=md.digest(seed);

        byte[] raw =new byte[32];

     System.arraycopy(temp, 0, raw, 0, temp.length);
       System.arraycopy(temp, 0, raw, temp.length, temp.length);



     return raw;
     //    return null;
 }


 private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
     SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES/ECB/NoPadding");
         Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
     cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
     byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
         return encrypted;
 }



 public static String toHex(String txt) {
         return toHex(txt.getBytes());
 }
 public static String fromHex(String hex) {
         return new String(toByte(hex));
 }

 public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) {
         int len = hexString.length()/2;
         byte[] result = new byte[len];
         for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                 result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2*i, 2*i+2), 16).byteValue();
         return result;
 }

 public static String toHex(byte[] buf) {
         if (buf == null)
                 return "";
         StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2*buf.length);
         for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
                 appendHex(result, buf[i]);
         }
         return result.toString();
 }
 private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";
 private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {
         sb.append(HEX.charAt((b>>4)&0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b&0x0f));
 }
}
```

but im getting this error

> java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default
>   parameters
>         at javax.crypto.Cipher.checkCryptoPerm(Cipher.java:1010)
>         at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:785)
>         at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:848)
>         at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1212)
>         at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1152)
>         at SimpleCrypto.encrypt(SimpleCrypto.java:53)
>         at SimpleCrypto.encrypt(SimpleCrypto.java:11)
>         at start.main(start.java:12)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow (SO)! When you have a specific problem (like converting a specific part of code to another language), it is best to include everything that you tried and any issue that you have run into doing this. SO is not a code writing service. We expect you to do at least some of the work. When you do, you will get better answers. When you try it yourself, include example strings to verify that the encryption worked.

Comment: Please add start.java and mark the lines from the stacktrace in the code with comments.

Comment: Can you change the VB.net code? It's broken in several ways.

Comment: @CodesInChaos On the bright side, the `getRawKey` is still better than the one from Android snippets :P

Answer (score 0):

First use ECB is bad and must be avoided, use CBC instead if you can change in both vb.net and java.
https://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2010/12/08/encryption-operating-modes-ecb-vs-cbc/

The problem probably comes from the size of your key, because of US law restriction. To change this restriction sees oracle documentation and edit your jdk / jre :

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html